# Error: Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding

Tags: c++, http, chunked-encoding

I'm writing my own http server and right now I'm trying to tmplement chunked transfer encoding. My attempt looks like this:

```
void HttpServer::SendRespons(HttpServer::Connection &socket_) noexcept {
  int sent = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  int index = 0;
  std::size_t response_size_;
  std::ifstream t(this->conf_.GetRootPath() + socket_.data);
  socket_.respons = {(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
  t.clear();
  response_size_ = socket_.respons.size();
  std::vector<std::string> strVec;
  strVec.reserve(socket_.respons.size() / BUFSIZE + 2);
  strVec.push_back(
      "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: http\r\nContent-Type: "
      "text/html\r\nTransfer-Encoding: "
      "chunked\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");
  while (index + 16374 < static_cast<int>(response_size_)) {
    strVec.push_back("3ff6\r\n" + socket_.respons.substr(index, 16374) +
                     "\r\n\r\n");
    index += 16374;
  }
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << std::hex
         << std::atoi(std::to_string(response_size_ - index).c_str());
  strVec.push_back(stream.str() + "\r\n" +
                   socket_.respons.substr(index, response_size_ - index) +
                   "\r\n\r\n");
  strVec.push_back("0\r\n\r\n");
  index = 0;
  response_size_ += (strVec[0].size() + strVec[strVec.size() - 1].size());

  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(this->connected_clients_mux_);
  while (index < static_cast<int>(strVec.size())) {
    int len =
        write(socket_.socket, (char *)&strVec[index][0], strVec[index].size());

    if (len < 0) {
      //...
      } else if ((errno == EPIPE) || (errno == ECONNRESET)) {
        std::cout << __FILE__ << " " << __func__
                  << " sent stop (epipe || econreset), len= " << len << " "
                  << "error #" << errno << std::endl;
        break;
      //...
    }
    ++index;
    sent += len;
    std::cout << __FILE__ << " " << __func__ << " sent " << len << " "
              << "packet #" << ++counter << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl
            << __FILE__ << " " << __func__
            << " assumed length:" << response_size_
            << " sent:" << sent << " to: " << socket_.socket << std::endl;
}
```

The above function should read the file, split it into parts and pass them one by one. As far as I can tell, the splits are going fine, but when trying to send a file:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/filename
```

i am getting:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /filename HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: http
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< 
//.... here is first chunk
* Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding
```

as you can see, the client receives the first part of the response (headers) and processes them. After - it expects the body of the message. Having received the first part of it, the connection is closed. I understand that the error is as written in the message somewhere in the format of my own chunk, but I myself cannot figure out exactly where. I followed instruntions from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Format but obv made a mistake.
Since the client does not output anything for the hexadecimal sequence it expects, nothing for the hexadecimal sequence it received and considered in error i ask about help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only one `\r\n` is needed at the end of this portion of code.

```
    strVec.push_back("3ff6\r\n" + socket_.respons.substr(index, 16374) +
                     "\r\n\r\n");
```

You should not insert an empty line between the previous chunk and the hexadecimal size of the next chunk.
(and the same goes for the last chunk)

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Format) you provide inserts empty lines between chunks in the example just in order to increase readability, but these empty lines are not actually sent.